# Trying to do math in .format

Tags: python, discord.py

It does the subtraction, but not the floor decision and adding

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")


@bot.event

async def on_message(message):
  if 0 < int(message.content) < 153:
   await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 1.  You are {} games away from Bronze 2".format(153 - int(message.content)//7 +1))
  if 153 < int(message.content) < 200:
   await message.channel.send("you are in Bronze 2")
```

Comment: As a hint: you can use the `range()` function for better code readability.
Like so: `if int(message.content) in range (1, 153):`

Comment: What was `message` when you got your unexpected output ?

Comment: Also, please include your intent of this mathematical expression `153 - int(message.content)//7 +1`. Its hard to tell the correct values, if no one here knows what the result should be. You should also include the current, and desired output in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't use a bracket, the order where `153 - int(message.content)//7 +1)` is ordered the same as `153 - (int(message.content)//7) + 1` as multiplication/division comes before addition/subtraction. Judging from the math I'm guessing that's not what you wanted.

Also some side notes:

- When if `int(message)` is 153 the input is completely ignored
- You should use an `elif` for the second block since it's non-overlapping.

Comment: Sry I don’t really understand